# Racket: Conditional Statements Not Matching String Equality in ToDo-List Programm

Tags: scheme, racket

**Problem Description:**

I'm working on a simple to-do list in Racket to better familiarize myself with the language, but I'm running into an issue where the conditional statements don't match string equality correctly.

**Code:**

```lisp
(define (todo)
  (define lst (call-with-input-file "todo.txt"
                (lambda (des)
                  (read des))))
  (display "Choose between these options:\nShow List,\nAdd ToDo,\nRemove ToDo,\nClear List\n")
  (define action (string-downcase (string-trim (read-line))))
  (cond
    [(eq? action "show list") (display lst)]))
```

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the program to output `lst` when `action` matches the string `show list`.

**Actual Behavior:**

The program consistently outputs nothing even when `action` matches `show list`.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `eq?` to compare strings. Use `equal?`

Comment: See also: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html

Comment: (I prefer [`string=?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string~3d~3f%29%29) instead of `equal?` when comparing string values, but there's not a huge practical difference here)

Comment: Since you're a new user, I'll make a clarification that I usually leave unsaid: having your question closed as a duplicate doesn't mean it's a bad question. In addition to voting to close, I upvoted it because it's clear and well-asked; the duplicate closure just makes it easy for you (and any future readers) to find the pre-existing, well-answered version of the question.